# How to display point features w.r.t field values of a polygon file in arcobjects?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-9.3, arcgis-desktop

I have a point & polygon shapefile. Point file has a field namely, **Type**: atm,hospital,school etc... Polygon file has a field **Zone**: Zn1, Zn2, Zn3. There will be two combo boxes which will populate this two fields respectively

What i like to do is.......If i select school & Zn2 in the comboboxes and click the "Show" button...... only schools which fall under the **Zn2** polygon should be displayed. W.r.t arcobjects, i m just a beginner. Trying this for the past two days. Can anyone help me regarding this ? Thanks in advance...

(ArcGIS Version 9.3 )

Answer (score 1):

Your onSelection combo box event needs to fire off this property:

[IFeatureLayerDefinition.DefinitionExpression Property](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/8.3/componenthelp/esricore/IFeatureLayerDefinition.htm)

to only show those features within the layer.

Here is a code snippet you can reference:

http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/8.3/componenthelp/esricore/IFeatureLayerDefinition_Example.htm

Comment: It works only for the features within a same shapefile. What i like to do is...........  

Select "Point features which has certain id" from "polygon features which has certain id".